# Perceptron learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I would like to interpret problem on picture below, which is about perceptron learning. It is about supervised learning wiht a training set, so correctness of values should be checked against a predefined set of values. I don't exactly know, how `A, B` and `bias(b)` values come. Could you please explain meaning of these and how these computed and changed during the learning process?

[image: perceptron learning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an intuitive, visual, interactive and beautiful guide to the basics concepts of neural networks:
https://jalammar.github.io/visual-interactive-guide-basics-neural-networks/

It will problably solve all your doubts. However, if you still have more questions after the reading, you will be able to ask something more specific. Enjoy!

Comment: That is great, thanks for the link, but I would like to do these on a paper, manually.

Comment: Welcome! Yes, the examples are quite simple, you should be able to reproduce it manually, on a paper. After that, for sure you can face with your example. Or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Yes, I see, that there are 2 weights in my example, but don't know how to modify bias after calculating Y value.

Comment: Yeah, first you have to read carefully (and understand) the information in the link, then you will know how to modify the bias.